# How to retrieve only LocalDate from LocalDateTime in Database(PostgreSQL)?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa, localdatetime

I need to retrieve distinct LocalDate from LocalDateTime in database. I can use Spring data JPA or SQL native query.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide at least [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to reproduce the problem.

Comment: show your entity and your query

Comment: In SQL you can cast the column to a date: `the_timestamp_column::date`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do something like this :

```
@Query(value="select * from posts where published_at Between ?1 And ?2", nativeQuery = true)
    Page<Posts> findAllPostsByPublishedDate(LocalDate dateFrom, LocalDate dateTo, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks.
I already do something like that, nativeQuery is necessary for me here